# How to post data in Angular ngForm and acomponent ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-form

How can I be able to post may data using this angular ngForm?
I really have trouble doing this part I need your experience in this one.

I added my service.ts below. I am really new to this one I hope anyone can give me insights.

Thank you in advance guys!!

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextService } from './text.service'
import { Text } from './text';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [TextService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public textService:TextService){}
    
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getTexts()
  }

    getTexts(){
      this.textService.getTexts()
      .subscribe(( res ) => {
        this.textService.texts = res as Text[];
      })
    }
postText(formValue){
    this.textService.postText(formValue).subscribe( res => {
        this.getTexts();
        this.textService.selectedText = new Text()
    });
}
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextService } from './text.service'
import { Text } from './text';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [TextService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public textService:TextService){}
    
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getTexts()
  }

    getTexts(){
      this.textService.getTexts()
      .subscribe(( res ) => {
        this.textService.texts = res as Text[];
      })
    }
    
    postText(formValue){
      this.textService.postText(formValue).subscribe( res => {
         this.getTexts();
         this.textService.selectedText = new Text()
       });
 }
}
```

**app.components.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let text of  textService.texts">
  <h1> {{ text.some_text }} </h1>
</div>

<form #textForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="postText(textForm.value)">
  <label for="some_text">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="some_text" name="some_text" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="textService.selectedText.some_text"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your typescript is not well formed for a start.

```
 postText(textForm=NgForm){
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.getTexts()
        this.textService.selectedText = new Text()
      })
```

You are subscribing to nothing on the first line inside this method. Instead you should use presumably your text service (where I assume you use http) to post the form value which you have passed in from the html. Something like the following:

```
 postText(formValue){
     this.textService.post(formValue).subscribe( res => {
        this.getTexts();
        this.textService.selectedText = new Text()
      });
}
```

Comment: .post "Property 'post' does not exist on type 'TextService'.ts(2339)"

Comment: I updated my script in my question. with your answer ang maybe the form in html was wrong. can you please check it out?

Comment: That looks correct. You need to implement post (you used postText) on your service within which you use httpclient to post the form and return the observable.

Comment: Hi I added my app.service.ts can you check it?

Comment: I would recommend you go through the documentation on posting data to the server here: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request